# disabling children of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Suppose I have a hierarchy like this:

```
JPanel panel1;
   JCheckBox cb1;
   JCheckBox cb2;
   JRadioButton rb1;
   JRadioButton rb2;
     ...
```

I have a condition where I want to set individual groups of controls within the panel to be enabled/disabled. That works fine. (e.g. enable cb1 and cb2 when one condition is true, disable them when it is false.)

I would like to disable and re-enable the whole panel. If I call `panel1.setEnabled(false)` this does not work, it only disables the panel, but does not affect its children.

If I enumerate the panel's children, and call `setEnabled(false)` on each of them, that would work, but then I would have to store the child enabled state when I re-enable the panel.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `isEnabled()` doesn't help to avoid state storing?

Comment: Good question. But I doubt it is doable this way. I think you'll have to sort it out "manually".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable a container and its children in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305527/how-to-disable-a-container-and-its-children-in-swing)

Comment: (oops, it's a duplicate, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

> If I enumerate the panel's children, and call setEnabled(false) on each of them, that would work, but then I would have to store the child enabled state when I re-enable the panel.

The [Disabled Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/) entry has a solution for this approach as well as a "container level" glass pane approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a glass pane over the panel to have it intercept the events.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Answer (score 1):

[JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/) is a great way to achieve it. It can be used for any Swing component.

Answer (score 1):

```
//una forma de recorrer todos los elementos dentro de un jpanel
Component[] components = jPanelX.getComponents();

for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {

    if(components[i].getClass().getName().toString().equals("javax.swing.JTextField")){
        components[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to call getName and toString on the class. Just do `components[i].getClass().equals(JTextField.class)` to disable all JTextFields.