# Java - disable DEFAULT_LAYER of JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jlayeredpane

I've got a JLayeredPane where my `MODAL_LAYER` is neatly covering the everything, and it's all generally going pretty well.

But there's a fly in the soup - the layers underneath still have functionality, even though they're visually hidden by the `MODAL_LAYER`.

Is there a neat way to "turn off" the lower layers, or pass all functionality to the `MODAL_LAYER`, or similar?

Seems like an easy question, maybe I'm having one of those moments.

**EDIT**

It may be possible to deny focus to any below layers, similar to JDialog, where nothing is allowed to happen except for direct interaction with the dialog?

Comment: On the hunt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305527/how-to-disable-a-container-and-its-children-in-swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a glass pane and intercept events that don't go to a component of your modal layer. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: doesn't help with events other than mouseEvent, afair