# Is it possible to invert all booleans within a Java class?

Tags: java

i have written a Java class in which i set the invisibility/visibility of certain JButtons, Labels and Texts.

I also want to build in a "Reset" Button in which everything looks like as if the program has just started, so my question: Is it possible to invert all booleans within a class in order to not write a new class or commands to set the visibility ?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

the class looks basically like this:

void Visible(){

```
    jLA.setVisible(true);
    jLB.setVisible(true);
    jBÜbernehmen2.setVisible(true);
    jLN.setVisible(true);
    jLNA.setVisible(true);
    jLNote.setVisible(true);
    jLS.setVisible(true);
```

}

All Swing elements are initiated invisible.
I know i could just rewrite the commands but i thought there must be a better way to manage the properties of swing elements, since this might end up in a huge messy code.

Comment: function which set values is the suitable solution for it.

Comment: Show your java class so that we might be able to show you a solution

Comment: On click of reset button just call your java class again, it'll reset the page. Please share some code for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to **reset** booleans to their initial intended values rather than **invert** them, so I'll address the resetting part.

This is perhaps one of the crazier uses of the HashMap, but I daresay it might actually be practical.

First we're going to need a HashMap of `JComponents` as keys, mapped to their `boolean` visibilities as values, as a field.

```
HashMap<JComponent, Boolean> defaultVisibility = new HashMap<JComponent, Boolean>();
```

Let's say we have these buttons.

```
JButton foo = new JButton("Foo");
JButton bar = new JButton("Bar");
```

We go ahead and throw those buttons into the HashMap at the end of the constructor where we instantiate the panel.

```
defaultVisibility.put(foo, foo.isVisible());
defaultVisibility.put(bar, bar.isVisible());
```

To abstract this, let's say that you have a JFrame with seven dozen individual components. Hand-coding this is a nightmare. We can create a nice recurisve method to help us out.

```
public void setDefaultVisibility(JComponent j) {
    defaultVisibility.put(j, j.isVisible());
    for(JComponent c : j.getComponents()) {
        setDefaultVisibility(c);
    }
}
```

Now we have all the default statuses, and we can use this nifty void to set the visibility of every element to what it was when we set them.

```
public void makeDefaultVisibility() {
    for(Entry<JComponent, Boolean> j : defaultVisibility.entrySet()) {
        j.getKey().setVisible(j.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, @SklogW, I just did.

Answer (score 3):

try this code below , it inverts all the boolean typed fields by reflection and displays them:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    private boolean var1=false;
    private boolean var2=true;

    public void resetBooleanFields(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        List<Field> toReturn = new ArrayList<Field>();

        Field[] allFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field f : allFields)
        {
            Class<?> type = f.getType();
            if (type.equals(boolean.class))
            {
                try {
                    f.set(this,!(Boolean)f.get(this));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println(f.get(this));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test tst = new Test();
        tst.resetBooleanFields(Test.class);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use varargs method to perform the call for multiple components:

```
public static void setVisibleMulti(boolean v, JComponent ... components) {
    for (JComponent component : component)
        component.setVisible(v);
}

// example call
setVisibleMulti(true, jLA, jLB, jBÜbernehmen, ...........);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean test = false;
test = !test;
```

This is how you invert a boolean.  Create a method within the class that resets all the booleans.  The method needs to be public but the variables themselves can still be private.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "inverting all the booleans" doesn't achieve the goal of "resetting to original state".  If only some of the values have changed, inverting all values won't result in the original state.

If the object has a "default state" then it should be aware of that state on some level, right?  (Or at least be able to be supplied with some indicator of that state.)  Something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private boolean defaultValue = false;
    private boolean currentValue = false;

    public boolean getCurrentValue() {
        return currentValue;
    }

    public void setCurrentValue(boolean newValue) {
        this.currentValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Basically you'd need to *store* that original default state somewhere so that it can be known later in the application when the active state has changed.  Then to reset the object to its original state, just create a method which does that:

```
public void resetToDefault() {
    this.currentValue = this.defaultValue;
}
```

Simply repeat for any other values within the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a complete program to make sure I understood what Compass was driving at and hope it's OK to post as an Answer. I made a few changes to get it to compile and be free of warnings/suggestions (probably not all necessary) and added a couple of twists (choosing default visibility and renaming a method). Thanks, Compass, for a really nice outline. I understand hash maps better as a result and hope what I've posted will help somebody else.

```
package hashmaptoresetbooleans;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class HashMapToResetBooleans 
{
  static HashMap<JComponent, Boolean> defaultVisibility;

  public     HashMapToResetBooleans() 
  {
    HashMapToResetBooleans           .defaultVisibility = new HashMap<>(9);
  }

  public static void setDefaultVisibility(JComponent j, boolean v) 
  {
    defaultVisibility.put(j, v);

    for(Component c : j.getComponents()) 
    {
       setDefaultVisibility((JComponent) c, v);
    }
  }  

  public static void setToDefaultVisibility() 
  {
    for(Entry <JComponent, Boolean> j : defaultVisibility.entrySet()) 
    {
      j.getKey().setVisible(j.getValue());
    }
  }  

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    new HashMapToResetBooleans();

    JButton foo = new JButton("Foo");
    JButton bar = new JButton("Bar");

    setDefaultVisibility(foo, false);
    setDefaultVisibility(bar, true); 

    // ... later on ...
    foo.setVisible(true);
    bar.setVisible(false);

    // ... later yet ...
    setToDefaultVisibility();

    System.out.println(foo.isVisible());
    System.out.println(bar.isVisible()); 
  }
}
```