# JPanel repaint is not visible when Mouse Event is used

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, repaint

I was trying to create a simple animation: moving an oval inside a Panel. I did it. It moved smoothly. But when I try to add a button to the frame and use MouseEvent to trigger this animation, the animation freezes. I see the first oval and then, after a definite elapsed time, the last oval. This time is probably the net time that it would take to move across (calculating based on the given sleep time in my method). I have changed the event to MouseClick/MousePress and all others but the case is same. The animation works fine if I comment the listener related code and run my "animate()" method from the main method. Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

/*This is my main Class*/
class Curiosity{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //Instantiating MyFrames, the class with Frame and Panel
        MyFrames myFrames = new MyFrames();
        myFrames.frameSetup();
    }
}

class MyFrames{
    JFrame myFrame ;
    JButton button ;
    /*******Creating A JPanel Child Class******  
     * I am drawing the animation on this panel
     *****************************************/
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getWidth());
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(animationObjectX, animationObjectY, 30, 30);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    //creating reference to Panel
    MyPanel myPanel ;

    /******* A class to listen to mouse event on button**********
     ************************************************************/
    class ButtonListener implements MouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //calling the animation method
            animate();
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    }
    //Event Listener Class Reference
    ButtonListener bl;

    /******************************
     * MyFrame Class Constructor
     *****************************/
    MyFrames(){
    myFrame = new JFrame("my App");
    button = new JButton("press to move");
    myPanel = new MyPanel();
    bl= new ButtonListener();

    }
    /**************************************************
    ** coordinates for my animation object (here an oval)
    ** I increment these to create animation effect
    *************************************************/
    int animationObjectX;
    int animationObjectY;

    void frameSetup(){
        /************************************
        //Configuring Frame
        *************************************/
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setSize(600,300);
        myFrame.setLocation(200,200);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        /************************************
        //Adding panel to Frame
        *************************************/
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,myPanel);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        //adding mouse listener to button
        button.addMouseListener(bl);

    }
    /********* the animation method ***********
     * just changing coordinates and repainting
     ******************************************/
    void animate()  {
        for(int x = 0;x<100;x++){
            animationObjectX=x;
            animationObjectY=x;
            try {Thread.sleep(15);} catch (InterruptedException e){}
            myFrame.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but I noticed a few things. First, in your `paintComponent()`, you're calling `myFrame.setVisible(true);`, which shouldn't be necessary each time you paint. Do it once, like in the constructor. Also in the same method, you call `setColor()` to yellow, where do you set the background color? From what I see, both the background and the oval would be the same color.

Comment: setVisible(true) was something that I forgot to remove before posting my question here. I had put it when I had tried everything I knew. It was just a wild effort after things didn't work. Please ignore it. Regarding background: how can the animation work when animate() method is called from main(). The problem occurs when I add MouseEvent handler... Thanks for looking into it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the event dispatch thread. `repaint()` only marks the component for redrawing, and Swing does not have a chance to actually draw it in your animate loop. Use a swing Timer instead.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

It works if it's not called from the listener because your main is **not** running in the EDT - it **should** be, because initializing swing components outside EDT is unsafe. You should change the code to

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Instantiating MyFrames, the class with Frame and Panel
            MyFrames myFrames = new MyFrames();
            myFrames.frameSetup();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, You must have concluded from my code that I am newbie. Thanks to your cues, I am understanding threads/event dispatch. Though I have not fully understood your solution(my bad), it's coherent and I can see my mistake. I am working on it and will post the solution in next edit

Comment: +1 for Swing Timer advice :-) @AnuragPriyadarshi : Another variant being [JCompnent.paintImmediately(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), though some repercussions are attached with this approach. a small [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10352884/1057230) for which can be seen here.

Comment: This does not block the button until the animation is over, making it possible to start multiple simultaneous animations. Is there a way to block the entire GUI (with has lots of panels and widgets) until the animation is over?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus You could call `setEnabled(false)` on the part(s) of the UI you want to disable during the animation (and re-enable it after done). Disabling a window disables all interaction with the subcomponents, but does not change their look to disabled (That would have the advantage of making it obvious to the user that no interaction is allowed. Unfortunately, there's no built-in method for that, but it's not hard to write your own that works for typical cases).

Comment: There is no way to do `setEnabled` for "lots of panels and widgets". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305527/how-to-disable-a-container-and-its-children-in-swing One alternative is to show a modal `JDialog` with a progress bar or something.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I'm aware of that - that's why I included the caveat. Disabling an entire frame though *does* work (but does not change the look of the components, like I said), because frames are heavy weight components. For more selective disabling you'd need to write your own recursive method going through the desired component tree (with the issues mentioned in the question you linked to).